# WaitForSingleObject - do threads waiting form a queue?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mutex

If I set 3 threads to wait for a mutex to be release, do they form a queue based on the order they requested it in or is it undefined behaviour (i.e. we don't know which one will pick it up first)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is explicitly documented in the [SDK article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If more than one thread is waiting on a mutex, a waiting thread is selected. Do not assume a first-in, first-out (FIFO) order. External events such as kernel-mode APCs can change the wait order.

These kind of events are entirely out of your control.  So "undefined behavior" is an appropriate way to describe it.

Comment: In practice (though certainly not guaranteed), it is FIFO.

Answer (score 2):

The Mutex Object is mostly fair.  The APC case can occur but it is not that common. Especially if the thread is not doing I/O or is doing I/O using completion ports or synchronously.

Most of the Windows user-mode locks (SRWLock, CriticalSection) are unfair if you can acquire them without blocking but fair if you have to block in the kernel.  The reason it is done this way is to avoid lock convoys. The moment a fair lock becomes contended, every acquirer has to go through the scheduler and the context switch path before getting the lock. No one can 'skip  ahead' and just take the lock because they happen to be running. Thus the lock acquire time for the last thread in the queue increases by the scheduling and context switch time for each prior thread in the queue. The system does not recover from this state until external load is mostly removed because this is a stable condition.

For performance, I would recommend using one of the aforementioned user-mode locks since they are much faster than a kernel mutex, if they fit into your scenario.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for answering this question with a useful and authoritative answer. However, in the future, [please do not "sign" your posts.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) That just adds extra "noise" and is a practice that we discourage here. That said, there's nothing wrong with informing people that you're a member of the Windows Kernel team, and in fact, we encourage disclosure of this type of information. You should use the "about" field (also known as the big gray box) in your personal profile page to share information like this.

Answer (score 1):

The wake-up order is undefined, see

[Can a single SetEvent() trigger multiple WaitForSingleObject()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621707/can-a-single-setevent-trigger-multiple-waitforsingleobject)

Comment: elaborate and cite reliable sources

Comment: So if I have a loop that locks a mutex, does some stuff, then releases...the next iteration could pick up the lock before another thread has had time to lock it....if this is the case, what is considered a reasonable sleep time to allow another thread to lock the mutex?

Comment: If there is so much contention on the mutex that this matters, then are the threads that are contending not effectively serialized?  If they're serialized, why not use just one thread and no lock?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be very mixed opinions about this and no clear information anywhere. In this thread: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/are-events-fair-help-38447612.html some people seem to suggest that fairness of events is implemented using a simple fifo queue that ignores priorities, while others are saying that fairness should not be assumed.

Bottom line, I think you're better off not basing your logic on fairness, or wrapping an event with your own implementation that guarantees fairness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only one thread will be wake up and lock mutex. But order is undefined.